# Отрисовка JButton круглой формы

Tags: java, swing

Можно ли сделать `JButton` круглой формы? Если можно, то какими средствами?

Comment: У Swing есть какой-то формат LaF для этого. Больше, увы, не знаю.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно унаследоваться от `JButton` и переопределить методы:

1. `paintComponent` - отрисовываются внутренности компоненты.
2. `paintBorder` - здесь можно задать любую форму компоненте.

---

Пример:

```
public class CircleBtn extends  JButton {
    public CircleBtn(String text) {
        super(text);

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width, size.height);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            setForeground(Color.yellow);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
    }
}
```